# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Output error: Shape of output target [1, 1917, 4] does not match with the shape of the Tensor [1, 1917, 1, 4]

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

I've trained my own model for object detection with tensorflow and I got it working with Tensorflow mobile for android. Now since Tensorflow Lite is released and is going to replace mobile in the future I wanted to start working with it. The Tensorflow team provided a demo for TFLite for object detection (you can find it [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15633#issuecomment-377652630)). So I tried to get it working with my model but I got the error in the title. Here's the logcat :

```
05-17 11:18:50.624 25688-25688/? I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Camera orientation relative to screen canvas: 90
05-17 11:18:50.624 25688-25688/? I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Initializing at size 640x480
05-17 11:18:50.628 25688-25688/? I/tensorflow: MultiBoxTracker: Initializing ObjectTracker: 640x480
05-17 11:18:50.637 25688-25688/? I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Preparing image 1 for detection in bg thread.
05-17 11:18:50.689 25688-25707/? I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Running detection on image 1
05-17 11:18:52.496 25688-25707/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: inference
                                                   Process: org.tensorflow.lite.demo, PID: 25688
                                                   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Output error: Shape of output target [1, 1917, 4] does not match with the shape of the Tensor [1, 1917, 1, 4].
                                                       at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.copyTo(Tensor.java:44)
                                                       at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(Interpreter.java:154)
                                                       at org.tensorflow.demo.TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.recognizeImage(TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java:222)
                                                       at org.tensorflow.demo.DetectorActivity$3.run(DetectorActivity.java:242)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

**Note :** as a checkpoint to train the model I used **ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17** and the only thing I changed in the code is this (TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java):

```
  private static final int NUM_CLASSES = 3;
```

because I only have two objects to detect. Any help or information would much appreciated.

Comment: As the error mentions, you are passing an invalid dimension for output tensor. You can solve it just by changing the shape of the output tensor(Float Array) you are passing while fetching predictions

Comment: Did you solve this issue? i tried to change the shape of output and got similar Error

Comment: nope I didn't :/ I kept working with Tensorflow mobile since TFLite not ready yet for production projects.. I suggest you retrain your model with Mobilenet V2 SSDLite released in April. It is supposed to be faster by 35%. I tested it with TF mobile and got bad results , maybe it was meant for TFLite.. so give it a try maybe you won't encounter a problem with it. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem but here is how i solved it with a small hack:
in the "TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java" file create a new variable array:

```
float [][][][] temp1 = new float[1][NUM_RESULTS][1][4];
```

and then for your "outputMap" object replace:

```
outputMap.put(0, outputLocations);
```

by:

```
outputMap.put(0, temp1);
```

This will solve the shape miss-match problem. and also be sure to put the correct number of classes. For example i had only one class but in the .txt file, the first class is listed as "???" and then the second one is my actual class. Hence i had:

```
private static final int NUM_CLASSES = 2;
```

even if i only have one class. But those two hacks seem to solve the problem.

P.S: The TFLite version of the fronzen model seems to run even slower than the .pb extension(on my Samsung Galaxy S8 android API 26).

Comment: How to configure for a Multiple outputs from tflite model?